# Macro to Fill new added column with vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

The macro accesses the last sheet in the workbook (always the same format) and adds a column D, with a header. Until here all is well; the final step is where I get issues.

I want the new column filled with the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2;'Output'!$A:$B;2;FALSE).
```

Note that the current sheet is different from where the formula looks (sheet `Output`).

I have tried various codes that I found here and there... but I cannot manage to make it work correctly right.

Here how my code looks currently:

```
Sub ColumnInsert()

Dim rws As Long
rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

  Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select

  Range("D:D").EntireColumn.Insert

  Range("D1").Value = "BOX Number"

  Range("D2:D" & rws).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C2;'Output'!$A:$B;2;FALSE)"

End Sub
```

the last row of code is what does not work... could you please help me?

Comment: When asking a question like this it's very important to explain HOW something "doesn't work". That's missing in this question. To go back and add information to a question, use the [edit] link below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your language settings. If you write your formula in a worksheet you use ";" to separate the variables. In Vba you have to use "," so your formula would be:
`"=VLOOKUP(C2,'Output'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"`